# How do you align latex to left side of knitted pdf in rstudio?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pdf, r, rstudio

I'm creating a notebook in rstudio for the first time, and I need to knit a pdf with latex. At the moment, I have latex in the middle of the document, but I'd like it aligned to the left, as the red arrow indicates below.

[image: Latex in the middle of the document]

Here is what my code says at the moment:

```
#### **Part b:**

\begin{align*}
E[X] &=\sum_xP(X=x)x \\
&= P(X=0)\times0+P(X=30)\times30+P(X=80)\times80 \\
&= (0.6)(0) + (0.28)(30) + (0.12)(80) \\
&= 18
\end{align*}
```

How can I modify this code so that the latex is aligned to the left of the document?

Comment: Just this code fragment? or all equation in your document? For first, see `fleqn` environment defined in the `nccmath` package, for second, add `fleqno` as option to document class or to `amsmath` package .

Comment: @Zarko I'm not sure how to include packages, I'm not sure what an environment is and I'm not sure what a document class is. Until now, when makin R markdown files, I have just been writing text in combination with R code snippets, together with its output, and occasionally adding simple Latex maths with $ signs. I didn't realise there was so much more to it. Can you recommend a resource for learning how to use fleqno, fleqn, nccmath and amsmath? I have no idea how to get these things to work. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Basic about writing math in LaTeX you find in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics and in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics.  About `nccmath`: read package documentation.

Comment: Off-topic, but the header is not in bold font by default? Why the asteriks?

Comment: @Fran to make it bold

Comment: @Data  Okay, you do not see it. Please make two headers in the same document, one  with `####  **Part b**`  and the other with  `#### Part b` and tell me if you see the difference. At least using the default template,  mark the text of a header as bold font is useless, because it is already  a bold font.